# contenteditable shows markup at the result

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm using `contenteditable` as text input and I want to show (on a different div) the text input when the user click on 'Submit'.

Let's say the user types:

```
hello
hello
```

and I check

```
$('.answer_comments_editable').html();
```

then I get `"hello<div>hello</div>"`.

I don't want to show any html markup on my final display, so how can I avoid this and instead show the clean text?

Answer (score 0):

try the `textContent` property

```
var contenteditable = document.querySelector('.answer_comments_editable'),
    text = contenteditable.textContent;
```

Comment: i changed $('.answer_comments_editable').html() to $('.answer_comments_editable').textl() and its working. thanks

Comment: Don't copy-paste from the comment above 